# Nullable in Model Binding

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using ASP.NET Core with VS 2017. I want to allow the users to create an employee record where they can leave the address input field empty i.e. as optional field input.

Using [Bind("Name","Address")] always validates the inputs and the request will always fail when the address field is empty.

Here is the data model.

```
public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

and the Create method reading the parameters from Post request has a model binding as follows

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Name,Address")] Employee emp)
```

and the view has a default asp form using Employee Model.

```
<div class="col-md-10">
     <input asp-for="Address" class="form-control" />
     <span asp-validation-for="Address" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Is there any way to make the address input field as an optional input for Model Binding?

Comment: Can't you make it a regular form, remove `[Bind]` and make the `Name` required?

Comment: so that in Create Method will be .. public async Task<IActionResult> Create(string Name, string Address) ?

Comment: What do you mean _request will always fail_. You do not have any validation attributes applied to property `Address` so nothing will _fail_. Your property is `string` which is `nullable` (its a reference type)  so its already optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm very new to Asp.net core, but from what I've learned so far, this is how I would do it:

```
<form method="post" asp-controller="YourController" asp-action="Create"> 
    <div>
        <input asp-for="Name" placeholder="Name"/>
        <div class="stylized-error">
            <span asp-validation-for="Name"></span>
        </div>

        <input asp-for="Address" placeholder="Address"/>
        <div class="stylized-error">
            <span asp-validation-for="Address"></span>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        <div class="error-list" asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

You want `Address` to be optional which is by default true, so you actually want to make `Name` required:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

And your controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Employee emp) 
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        // Do whatever you want here...
    }
}
```

> A property is considered optional if it is valid for it to contain
>   null. If null is not a valid value to be assigned to a property then
>   it is considered to be a required property.

Later

> You can use Data Annotations to indicate that a property is required.

From [docs.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/required-optional)

Comment: already tried as per your suggestion but I still see an error "the Address field is required" on the browser :(

Comment: I tested my example myself and it works well. Make sure you did everything the way I wrote.

Comment: I have just realized i put [Required] on Address. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: And .. what if I have int Age {get; set;} in the model. I understand that integer is not nullable so could you please suggest me on how to make it nullable? (or do i need to use int? Age {get;set;} in model?)

Comment: Look in the link I provided